# C++ hour calculations

Tags: c++, time.h

how can i write a source code for the calculations of time? For example,the user enter at 2.45 pm and check out at 3.15 . If we use simple mathematics , 3.15-2.45=0.7 . But if we use hour calculations 3.15-2.45=0.3(30minutes) . please help me .

Comment: Here's a hint: an hour is sixty minutes.

Comment: Another hint: Use only integers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to store/memorize the check-in and check-out time in the standard time format (time_t), returned by the function 'time()'. I.e., a long representing the number of seconds since the Epoch.
After that, call 'difftime()' to determine the difference (expressed in seconds).
You can apply normal arithmetic operations in order to convert this duration into hours, minutes, ecc.